# Enable xml DOM in lamp

Tags: php, xml, lampp

All xml parsing functions are not working in local server, i am using LAMPP server with PHP Version 5.2.9, how to enable this?

i.e getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function domxml_open_mem() in .........
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? Can you show some code?

Comment: i.e getting the error:

    Fatal error: Call to undefined function domxml_open_mem() in .........

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are part of the DOM XML extension which is for PHP4 only, you can't use it on PHP >=5. And it should be deprecated for the same reason anyway ...

Check for alternatives in here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php